# HTML templates for repeating elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="spinner">
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.24s; border-color: #777;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.20s; border-color: #888;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.16s; border-color: #999;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.12s; border-color: #AAA;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.08s; border-color: #BBB;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.04s; border-color: #CCC;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.00s; border-color: #DDD;"></div>
    </div>
```

This along with some CSS, makes an animated spinner.

However it's quite messy, especially if I want to use it multiple times. I can use Javascript to create it but that's also a bit messy, I mean shouldn't the structure be kept to HTML? Is there a way to do something like:

```
<template name="spinner">
    <div class="spinner">
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.24s; border-color: #777;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.20s; border-color: #888;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.16s; border-color: #999;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.12s; border-color: #AAA;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.08s; border-color: #BBB;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.04s; border-color: #CCC;"></div>
        <div style="-webkit-animation-delay:0.00s; border-color: #DDD;"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<body>
    <template target="spinner" />
    <!-- Some other stuff -->
    <template target="spinner" />
</body>
```

(without using javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can only tidy up your CSS;

**CSS**

```
.spinner div {
    /* markup for all divs in here, like width, height etc. */
}

.spinner div:nth-child(1) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.24s; border-color: #777; }
.spinner div:nth-child(2) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.20s; border-color: #888; }
.spinner div:nth-child(3) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.16s; border-color: #999; }
.spinner div:nth-child(4) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.12s; border-color: #AAA; }
.spinner div:nth-child(5) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.08s; border-color: #BBB; }
.spinner div:nth-child(6) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.04s; border-color: #CCC; }
.spinner div:nth-child(7) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.00s; border-color: #DDD; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

The HTML can repeated anywhere. You can't repeat the inner div-tags by CSS. You'll have to do a small JavaScript innerHTML loop to achieve that. But as you want to avoid that, I'll show this as the only (known to me) example.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this without JavaScript. HTML5 has a shiny new [`<template>`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) tag, but it requires JavaScript to use.

HTML represents the logical structure of your page. It does not support this sort of thing.

You don't have to use JavaScript, you can use SSI (server side include), a server side language etc.

One option would be to build your HTML once using some form of JavaScript templating, and then serve this HTML to the users. That way no JavaScript code will run on the client-side (it will generate an HTML) and you'll be able to work with `<template>` tags in the way you suggest.

This would change your build process from `html` to `html+template => html` where the conversion is done by some templating engine/programming language. You still end up serving `html`.

Comment: I thought this might be the only option, it's just a little annoying HTML doesn't include this by default.

Comment: @Jonathan. I agree, it makes some sense to seperate HTML from this sort of logic. I do however, see the big need to do this sort of things in HTML that can't contain JavaScript (email messages for example). I handled this issue by the two-phase process I described. I've read the HTML specification and follow the changes and drafts closely, sadly, there is no way to do this with HTML.

Comment: @Jonathan. The only tag I know of that can "include" code is `iframe` which is **bad** ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV an iframe does not "include code", it does something completely different. It includes an entire documents with its own DOM tree. It's not just bad, it's _different_

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, prehaps it should be seperate, but it's just nice to be able to open notepad or another textbox and be able to create web pages. In programming languages it is generally bad to repeat code, yet in HTML (and CSS with browser prefixes) it seems you have to repeat markup a lot.

Comment: @Jonathan. I agree, this is part of the reason why stuff like SASS and LESS exist for CSS (which are also compiled through the same stage process.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you generate the HTML with a server side script, no, HTML is `static` by itself. If you want to alter the DOM, then you need to use Javascript.

What you can do is leave your template in a hidden div with a certain id, and use Javascript to get it with `getElementById` and then clon that div and place it wherever and as much times you want.

If you write a function on Javascript for that, then you can place simple tags between your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">place_div()</script>
```

HTH

Francisco

Comment: Javascript was not "just my answer". I started by explaining that it's not possible with just HTML, and then explained why and how Javascript is needed. Did you seriously down-voted my answer with that lack of criteria?

Comment: So, it would be better to just "cut" the answer in "Not possible"? What an attitude, man.

Comment: Yes, and with reason. Check the other answer by itsstephyoutrick; suggestions and information-aquiring goes through comments. Don't give answers that are excluded by the OP unless you have a good reason. You don't give a valid reason, just a simple alternative. Imagine all the people who have knowledge of this subject answering like this; by that time this question would already have 100's of answers like that. It doesn't help the OP. Only answer with negligence if you can prove (by docs/facts) there is no other way to solve the OP's question.

Comment: I did give a valid reason: `HTML is static by itself. If you want to alter the DOM, you need to use Javascript.`. It wasn't about ignoring the OP.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo That was an edit though. Downvoter might have voted before that edit and not return to the question. Don't take votes so personally, we all know you're here to help. Allendar (or some one else) didn't find your answer useful for this question, that's all a down-vote means (and it is also why a downvote is -2 and an upvote is +10). We all know you're here to help.